# Is there a way to mirror the pose of the left hand to the right hand?

Tags: modeling, bones

[image]

I tried to copy and paste each bone but it turns the right hand's pose into something different

Comment: Hello, maybe the bones are not correctly oriented, you need to check in Edit mode, or please share your file

Comment: You need the bones to have the same names as the opposite, ones ending in '.L' and the others in '.R' for eft and right side respectively. When you copy the pose of one side select the bones of the hand and do Ctrl+C. When you past them on the other side, select the bones and hit Ctrl+Shift+V, otherwise it doesn't paste the mirrored pose